# Перемещение составного элемента

Tags: c#, winforms

Пытался написать собственный элемент для WinForms да вот только получилась какая-то лажа (Только начал интересоваться в этой теме) сам элемент получился я могу добавить его на форму вот только обработка событий с него не происходит, а если точно то пока что работает только _Load, а связанные с мышью нет (хотел реализовать перемещение этого элемента по форме) сначала нашел класс для перемещения он прекрасно работал с стандартными элементами, с моим нет позже написал код на обработке трех условий мыши также результатов не дало (с стандартными все также работает).
Прошу помощи для меня такого чайника)))
Что именно скинуть конкретно не уверен поэтому прикрепил все полностью.

```
using CustomControl;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using static System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement;

namespace Block_schematics
{
    public partial class FormMain : Form
    {

        public FormMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CustomControl.StartControl startControl = new CustomControl.StartControl();
            // Сначала использовал класс, но позже подумал что стоит попробовать что-то самому напсиать
            startControl.MouseUp += startControl_MouseUp;
            startControl.MouseMove += startControl_MouseMove;
            startControl.MouseDown += startControl_MouseDown;
            startControl.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
            MoveCtrl.EnableMove(startControl);
            panel1.Controls.Add(startControl);

        }

        private bool check = false;
        private Point cursor;
        private Point ob_ctrl;

        private void startControl_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            check = false;
        }

        private void startControl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (check)
            {
                (sender as UserControl).Location = new Point
                    (ob_ctrl.X + (Cursor.Position.X - cursor.X),
                    ob_ctrl.Y + (Cursor.Position.Y - cursor.Y));
            }
        }

        private void startControl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            check = true;
            cursor = Cursor.Position;
            ob_ctrl = (sender as UserControl).Location;
        }


        private void startControl1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Не как не реагирует на клик");
        }
    }
}
```

Код элемента

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CustomControl
{
    public partial class StartControl: UserControl
    {
        public StartControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (label1.Height > 0)
            {
                var ky = label1.Height / 2;
                label1.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", ky);
                Console.WriteLine($"{this.Height}, {this.Width}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Код дизайна контрола

```
namespace CustomControl
{
    partial class StartControl
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Обязательная переменная конструктора.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Освободить все используемые ресурсы.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">истинно, если управляемый ресурс должен быть удален; иначе ложно.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Код, автоматически созданный конструктором компонентов

        /// <summary>
        /// Требуемый метод для поддержки конструктора — не изменяйте 
        /// содержимое этого метода с помощью редактора кода.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(StartControl));
            this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // pictureBox1
            // 
            this.pictureBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.pictureBox1.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
            this.pictureBox1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.pictureBox1.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("pictureBox1.Image")));
            this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.pictureBox1.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(125, 60);
            this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
            this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(127, 62);
            this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(40, 24);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(46, 15);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.label1.Text = "Начало";
            this.label1.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.label1_Resize);
            // 
            // StartControl
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
            this.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Hand;
            this.Name = "StartControl";
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(127, 62);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
    }
}
```

Постараюсь быстро отвечать на ваши вопросы по моему детищу (идею которую уже ненавижу)

Comment: Код дизайнера контрола покажите

Comment: Поправил смотрите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалась проблема в том что я на весь контрол натянул pictureBox котрый не давал нажать на сам контрол